# cannot find sqlpackage in Azure pipelines Microsoft hosted agent

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to use sqlpackage in a Powershell task within an Azure pipeline. I'm using a Microsoft hosted windows-2022 agent.

When I run sqlpackage inside the Powershell task I get:

```
sqlpackage : The term 'sqlpackage' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program
```

According to the Microsoft documentation, sqlpackage is included in the Microsoft-hosted Windows agents but I can't figure out where is sqlpackage located in the agent.

I tried running this script to determine the sqlpackage version from the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-pipelines?view=sql-server-ver15) but it doesn't work:

```
- script: sqlpackage.exe /version
  workingDirectory: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DAC\bin\
  displayName: 'get sqlpackage version'
```

And I tried a different file path that a StackOverflow post used and it didn't work either:

```
- script: sqlpackage.exe /version
  workingDirectory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\150\
  displayName: 'get sqlpackage version'
```

Both instances I received a `not found workingDirectory` error.

How do I access sqlpackage and other tools that come pre-installed on Microsoft-hosted agents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use Windows-2022 agent, the sqlpackage.exe indeed locate in the path: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DAC\bin\`

If you are using PowerShell task, you need to run the following script to use the sqlpackage.exe: `.\SqlPackage.exe argument`

```
- powershell: '.\SqlPackage.exe  /version'
  workingDirectory: 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DAC\bin\'
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
```

The script in the doc：[Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-pipelines?view=sql-server-ver15#azure-pipelines)  are for the Command Line task in Azure Pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain if this is still relevant but you can use the command:
dotnet tool update -g microsoft.sqlpackage
Then you can call SqlPackage from the powershell script